# C#. Почему не работает поиск с помощью Contains()?

Tags: c#, поиск, foreach

Есть код на C#, мне нужно переделать if ((product.Contains("mysql:mysql")) ||... так, чтобы строки брались из списка.

```
    public List<string> GetIDDesiredDB(List<EntryType> entries)
    {
        List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
        string id = "";
        //List<string> products = GetProductsList();

            foreach (EntryType entry in entries)
                if (entry.VulnerableSoftwareList != null)
                    foreach (string product in entry.VulnerableSoftwareList.Products)
                        if ((product.Contains("mysql:mysql"))
                                        || (product.Contains("microsoft:sql_server"))
                                        || (product.Contains("oracle:mysql"))
                                        || (product.Contains("oracle:database")))
                            if (id != entry.id)
                            {
                                IDs.Add(entry.id);
                                id = entry.id;
                            }

            return IDs;
        }
```

Делаю так, но у меня не заходит в if:

```
var products = GetProductsList(); // [ "mysql:mysql", "microsoft:sql_server", "oracle:mysql", "oracle:database" ]

    foreach (string product in products)
       if(entry.VulnerableSoftwareList.Products.Contains(product))
```

Comment: Может, у вас `products` пустой список?

Comment: мы, телепаты, сейчас угадаем, что скрывается за `var, var, var...`

Comment: @Igor: Вопрос не в типах, а в содержимом списка, как мне кажется. Что нам даст тот факт, что `entry` имеет тип `Entry`, в котором есть открытое поле/свойство `VulnerableSoftwareList`?

Comment: В методе Contains() используются лямбда выражения ? Или ```VulnerableSoftwareList.Products``` это просто ```string[]``` ?

Comment: @VladD список не пустой

Comment: @isnullxbh VulnerableSoftwareList.Products это List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public List<string> GetIDDesiredDB(List<EntryType> entries)
    {
        List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
        string id = "";
        List<string> products = GetProductsList();

        foreach (EntryType entry in entries)
            if (entry.VulnerableSoftwareList != null)
                foreach (string product in entry.VulnerableSoftwareList.Products)
                    foreach (string prod in products)
                        if (product.Contains(prod))
                        {
                            if (id != entry.id)
                            {
                                IDs.Add(entry.id);
                                id = entry.id;
                            }
                            break;
                        }

        return IDs;
    }
```

Всем спасибо, сделал так. Заработало

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да, верно

Comment: "Заработало" - но Вы поняли, почему заработало?

Comment: @FoggyFinder для того, чтобы id не дублировались

Comment: @Igor не совсем

Comment: @FoggyFinder мне нужно получить id того entry, который в entry.VulnerableSoftwareList.Products содержит хотя бы один элемент из списка products